# HTML5 Page Request

Tags: http, html, iframe, httprequest

I have been searching around for a way to simply request webpages with HTML5. Specifically, I want to do an HTTP(S) request to a different site. It sounds like this is not possible at first due to obvious security reasons, but I have been told this is possible (maybe with WebSockets?).

I don't want to use iframes, unless there is a way to make it so the external site being requested does not know that it is being requested through an iframe.

I've been having a really difficult time finding this information. All I want to do is load a webpage, and display it.

Does anyone have some code they could share, or some suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to to circumvent [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Don't do that :)

If it is just the request you want (and nothing else), there are a number of ways to do it, namely with `new Image` in JavaScript or `iframe`. The site will know it is in an `iframe` by checking `top.location.href !=  window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

funneling all your requests through a proxy might be a solution - the client addresses only the proxy and the actual url to retrieve would be a query string parameter.

best regards, carsten

Comment: Not what I want to do. That would kind of defeat the purpose.